# Load a selectbox from a persisted list of objects and use that selectbox value to load the full object from the selectbox

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a Hibernate table with my business object : campaign (Id, name, description, ...). Using Thymeleaf, I am preloading a select box with the campaign names. Once the user selects a name and I am trying to submit the campaign Id to the controller or since I have an arrays with all campaigns object, I would only pass the selected object from the selectbox.

What do you think would be the best way to do this ?

```
<div class="form-group blu-margin">
<form th:object="${campaign}" th:action="@{/campaign}" method="post">
    Select the campaign you would like to execute : 
    <select
        class="form-control" id="dropCampaign" name="dropCampaign">
        <option value="0">select campaign</option>
        <option th:each="INcampaign : ${campaigns}"
                th:value="${INcampaign.id}" 
                th:text="${INcampaign.name}">
        </option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where do you want to load, or what do you want to do, with the full campaign object? In any case, I feel this turning into the usual two choices: 1. Reload the page entirely with your object included, or 2. Make an AJAX call on select change and do whatever with the returned object using js.

Comment: Hi Jorge. Thanks for responding. I want to load another page with the details about the campaign. 

In fact, if we use the typical recipe-ingredients example. Page 1 = Select the recipe you want to edit from a dropbox. Page 2 = The recipe details from that selection from the previous page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading various articles and trying different things, I think I got it. Sharing my solution in case it can help someone. The trick is to add id and name in the select tag. Then of course, in your controller you need to add @RequestParam Long id in your method signature.

But note this is not the usual way to do this. The more standard way is to call a URL such as /campaign/{id}/edit. But I wasn't sure about the security because not all users have access to all the campaigns so I didn't want to expose the URL to this edit possibility (even if I am sure you can secure this somehow). For me, that way seems easier.

```
<form name="f" th:action="@{/campaign}" th:object="${campaign}" method="post">
<select id="id" name="id">
    <option value="0">select campaign</option>
    <option th:each="campaign : ${campaigns}"
            th:value="${campaign.id}" 
            th:text="${campaign.name}"
            >
    </option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```